# Text not shown over cylinder

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I am learning Blender and facing issue to fit text over cylinder. I want to place the text at the top and bottom of the cylinder, when I am placing text at the top of the cylinder it is hiding some part of the text. Below is screen shot:
[image: Text-over-cylinder]

I have added text "Front face" but it is hiding some text. Please suggest.

Comment: Please describe _how_ you are deforming the text. It may help others see what's up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to see from the screenshot, but I can see that your cylinder and maybe also text is rotated on the x- and y-axis - could it be that the cylinder is just cropping the text?